# TableView is not adding more than 2 TableCellView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, interface-builder

I have added a TableView using interface builder. Now i am trying to insert TableViewCellView into that TableView. Its just allowing me drop 2 CellView from the Library. As soon as i dropped 3rd CellView, it put it outside the TableView.

what i am doing wrong?

Following this tutorial
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It puts first and second UITableCellView as footer and header view of your table, custom views that you can put at top and bottom of your table. All contents of your table you should create in code. Read documentation about UITableViewDataSource - it's pretty simple.